# PhantomJs | FFMPEG Audio from website

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, phantomjs, audio-recording

I have the following `Phantom` script:

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 640, height: 480 };

page.open('http://ads-e-bauerse-fm-05-gos2.sharp-stream.com/popfm_dk_mp3', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Initial frame
        var frame = 0;
        // Add an interval every second
        setInterval(function() {
            frame++;
            if(frame > 10) {
                phantom.exit();
            }
        }, 1);
    }, 666);
});
```

Now i run this script with the following command (adding `ffmpeg`)

```
phantomjs hello.js | ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 left.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 right.wav
```

The error i get is: `stereo.wav: No such file or directory`

Now the goal of this operation is to open a website listen to the music played on the site for 10 seconds then add that as an audio file in my project.

My question is what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately PhantomJS only supports opening web pages.

---

I'd suggest using streamripper for what you want to do:

```
apt-get install streamripper -y
streamripper http://ads-e-bauerse-fm-05-gos2.sharp-stream.com/popfm_dk_mp3 -l 10 -k 0 -A -a stream.mp3
```

Where `-l` is rip length in seconds

Comment: is there a windows version of streamripper

Comment: Yes, there seems to be: https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamripper/files/streamripper%20%28current%29/

Comment: exactly what i was looking for perfect thank you mate